# Retrieve Hex color from database to use as site's primary color

Tags: css, angularjs, laravel, colors

I have a form where a user can select a color from a color picker and it is then saved to the database. **My objective is to be able to pull back that color from the database and use it as the site's primary color(like a theme), eg: navbar header and button colors**. The user will also have the option to select a secondary color, but for now just the primary color will be attempted.

How can I do this using **Laravel** and **Angularjs** as my frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about storing the selected color and adding a class to the body like so:

```
<body class="{{ $color }}">
```

Then you can style the site using that class as a "hook" like this:

```
body.red { ... }
body.green { ... }
body.blue { ... }
```